# Some questions about a proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Proposition:** a countable union of countable sets is countable.

*Proof:* Write $X=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}} A_i$ where $|A_i|\leq|\mathbb{N}|$ and, without loss of generality, $A_i\bigcap A_j=\varnothing$ for all $i\neq j$.
Let $Q_n=\{q\in\mathbb{Q}:\;n-1< q\leq n\}$ for $n\geq 1$. Since $|Q_n|=|\mathbb{N}|$ we can consider an injection $\phi:\;A_i\to Q_i$ for each $i$.

Then $\phi: X\to \bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}} Q_i=\mathbb{Q}^+$ and hence $|X|\leq |\mathbb{Q}^+|=|\mathbb{N}|\Rightarrow X$ is countable.

---

This is fairly new to me, so I'd like to check that what I'm doing is acceptable:

- have I used the axiom of choice?
- is it alright to claim the existence of a $\phi$, as I have?
- is it acceptable to use $|\mathbb{Q}|=|\mathbb{N}|$ here, or is this a bit circular? (does the traditional 'counting along the diagonals' argument (to show $|\mathbb{Q}|=|\mathbb{N}|$) use the proposition above, in disguise? $-$ a fear of this is the reason I didn't use the argument to prove the main proposition)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes. You have used the axiom of choice. You chose an injection $\phi_i$ for every $A_i$. Note that if $|A|=|\Bbb N|$ then there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ bijections between $A$ and $\Bbb N$. Picking one for each $i$ is not a trivial matter.
2. Not quite. When we write $f\colon X\to Y$ we mean that the domain of $f$ is $X$. So you should write $\phi_i\colon A_i\to\Bbb Q_i$, and then since $A_i$'s are pairwise disjoint, claim that $\phi=\bigcup\phi_i$ is a well-defined function from $X$ into $\Bbb Q$.
3. It's fine to use the fact that $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb N$ are both countable. We can prove directly that $\Bbb Q$ is countable, and we don't use this theorem for that.

Comment: That was quick! Thank you!